# Populate table with array with multiple index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

after an ajax cal I can print the following result:

```
Array(3)
0: [{Col1: "Value", Col2: "Value" }]
1: [{Col1: "Value", Col2: "Value" }]
2: [{Col1: "Value", Col2: "Value" }]
```

What I'm trying to do is to populate a table with a for loop. Here is what I'm trying to use.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "apiurl",
    data: {},
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        var json = data;
        var html = "";

        for (var x = 0; x < json.length; x++) {
            html += "<tr><td>" + json[x].Col1+ "</td><td>" + json[x].Col2+ "</td></tr>";
        }

        $('#Table').html("");
        $('#Table').html(html);         
    }
});
```

This code doesn't populate the table but if I do this change:

```
var json = data[0];
```

The table is populated with the values from the array with index 0, so my question is, what can I do to populate my table with the values of all the index.

Comment: `data` has an array at each index. Use `json[x][0].Col1` instead of `json[x].Col1` Or, use `var json = data.flat()` and keep the existing loop

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `data` is an array of arrays. You need to flatten this:

```
var json = data.map((entry) => entry[0]);
```

You can also use the [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method:

```
var json = data.flat();
```